# Не работает правильно flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Изучаю флексбоксы и у меня возник вопрос: почему не работает правильно css если добавить картинку на фон?

```css
header {
  padding-top: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}

.contact {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}


/*Если росскоментировать тогда header не будет двигатся
.container {
    background-image: url("../image/background.jpg");
    height: 883px;
    width: 960px;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Travelling to Asia</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      <h2>Contact us</h2>
      <p>+12 34 567 8910</br>
        info@asia-holidays.com</p>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Что конкретно неправильно работает? У меня все нормально. Вы в container жестко задаете  ширину и высоту, соответственно, flex работает в этих ограничениях. Или вы что-то другое имеете ввиду?

Comment: @mr.smile мне нужно было удалить атрибуты ширины и высоты и тогда все получилось